# Matrix calculus: Second-order derivative matrix using chain rule

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule, hessian-matrix

Let's consider three sets of vectors, dependent on each other as follows:
$\textbf{A}=\textbf{A}(\textbf{B})$, $\textbf{B}=\textbf{B}(\textbf{C})$

Using the chain rule,
$ \dfrac{d\textbf{A}}{d\textbf{C}}=\dfrac{d\textbf{A}}{d\textbf{B}}\dfrac{d\textbf{B}}{d\textbf{C}}$

How can one expand this rule to calculate the second order derivative matrix $\dfrac{d^2\textbf{A}}{d\textbf{C}^2}$ if $\dfrac{d^2\textbf{A}}{d\textbf{B}^2}, \dfrac{d^2\textbf{B}}{d\textbf{C}^2}$ are also known?

I was thinking something like $\dfrac{d^2\textbf{A}}{d\textbf{C}^2}= \dfrac{d\textbf{B}}{d\textbf{C}}^T \dfrac{d^2\textbf{A}}{d\textbf{B}^2} \dfrac{d\textbf{B}}{d\textbf{C}} + \dfrac{d\textbf{A}}{d\textbf{B}} \dfrac{d^2\textbf{B}}{d\textbf{C}^2}$ that reminds of the multivariable function second-order chain rule, but I don't think it holds.

Thanks for all the tips!

edit: I am using the Python NumPy package, so I can add over any matrix axes using tensordot.

EDIT: Using einsum of the NumPy package, one can write:

```
dAdC=np.einsum('ik,km->im',dAdB,dBdC)
DADC=np.einsum('ikl,km,ln->imn',DADB,dBdC,dBdC)+np.einsum('ik,kmn->imn',dAdB,DBDC)
```

for the first (small d) and second order (capital D) derivatives, respectively.

Comment: I'm not sure your expression is correct because the second order derivatives should form a 3-tensor (See [here for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Vector-valued_functions). It isn't clear how you would combine this with the 2-tensors given by, e.g. $dA/dB$.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\G#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\H#1#2#3{\LR{\hess{#1}{#2}{#3}}}
$Write the first derivative using [Index Notation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EinsteinSummation.html) (wherein repeated indices are summed over)
$$
\grad{A_i}{C_k}
 = \G{B_p}{C_k} \G{A_i}{B_p} 
 \;\equiv\; {\large\sum_{p=1}^n}\G{B_p}{C_k} \G{A_i}{B_p} 
$$
Continue to the second derivative by operating with $\G{}{C_j}$ using the product rule,
$$\eqalign{
\hess{A_i}{C_j}{C_k}
 &= \H{B_p}{C_j}{C_k} \G{A_i}{B_p}
  + \G{B_p}{C_k} \c{\grad{}{C_j} \G{A_i}{B_p}} \\
}$$
Then use the chain rule on that $\c{\rm last\;term}$
$$\eqalign{
\hess{A_i}{C_j}{C_k}
 &= \H{B_p}{C_j}{C_k} \G{A_i}{B_p}
  + \G{B_p}{C_k} \c{\G{B_q}{C_j} \H{A_i}{B_q}{B_p}} \\
}$$
Note that the expression for the Hessian is a third-order tensor (aka a $\sf 3D$ array) but it should work quite nicely with the $\sf Einsum$ package.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the tensors are combined, I think your expression might make sense now.

I've used $x$, $y$ and $z$ for $C$, $B$ and $A$ respectively in the work below, hope it makes sense:

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $y$ depend on $x$ so we can find the Jacobian of $y$ as a function of $x$.

$$
J_x y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \qquad
\left. J_{x} y \right|_{i,j}
= \frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}
$$

where $J|_{i,j}$ denotes the $(i,j)$ element of the Jacobian.

Let $z \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$ be a function of $y$. We can also find the Jacobian of $z$ as a function of $y$.

$$
J_y z \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n} \qquad
\left.
J_{y} z \right|_{t,i}
= \frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
$$

We can view $z$ as a function of $x$ by composition

$$
x \rightarrow y \rightarrow z \qquad \qquad
\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow
\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow
\mathbb{R}^{k}
$$

The Jacobian of $z$ as a function of $x$:

$$
J_x z \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times m} \qquad
\left.
J_{x} z \right|_{t,j}
= \frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial x_{j}}
$$

The term

$$
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial x_{j}}
$$

Can be written as a sum

$$
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial x_{j}}
=
\sum_{i=1}^{n}
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
\frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}
$$

Let's drop the summation and use Einstein notation, i.e. we assume summation over indices that are repeated, so we can write

$$
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial x_{j}}
=
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
\frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}
$$

This basically represents matrix multiplication.
The Jacobians are matrices (2-tensors) and we have

$$
J_{x} z = J_{y} z \; \; J_{x} y
$$

What about the Hessian? - is there a chain rule for Hessians?

The Hessian of $y$ as a function of $x$ is

$$
H_{x} y = \nabla_{x} J_{x} y
$$

It is a 3-tensor
$$
\left.
H_{x} y \right\vert_{q,i,j} = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{q}}
J_{x} y \vert_{i,j}
$$

$$
\left.
H_{x} y \right\vert_{q,i,j} = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{q}}
\frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}
=
\frac{\partial^{2} y_{i}}{\partial x_{q} \, x_{j}}
$$

The Hessian of $z$ as a function of $y$ is

$$
\left.
H_{y} z \right\vert_{r,t,i} = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{r}}
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
=
\frac{\partial^{2} z_{t}}{\partial y_{r} \, y_{i}}
$$

What about the Hessian of $z$ as a function $x$?

$$
\left.
H_{x} z \right\vert_{s,t,j} = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{s}}
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial x_{j}}
=
\frac{\partial^{2} z_{t}}{\partial x_{s} \, x_{j}}
$$

We can use the expression derived earlier for $\partial z_{t}/\partial x_{j}$ which is an element in the Jacobian of $z$ with respect to $x$:

$$
\left.
H_{x} z \right\vert_{s,t,j} = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{s}}
\left[
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
\frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}
\right]
$$

Remembering that we are using the convention where repeated indices denote indices over which we should sum. The evaluates with the product rule to the following

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left.
H_{x} z \right\vert_{s,t,j} &
= 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{s}}
\left[
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
\frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}
\right]
\\
&=
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
\;
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{s}}
\frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}
+
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{s}}
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
\;
\frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}
\\
&=
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
\,
\frac{\partial^{2} y_{i}}{\partial x_{s} x_{j}}
+
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{s}}
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
\,
\frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}
\end{aligned}
$$

The first part of the second term contains components of all three variables, let's focus on it

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{s}}
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
$$

Assuming equality of mixed partials, we can write it as

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{i} }
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial x_{s}}
$$

Repeating the substitution made earlier,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{i} }
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial x_{s}}
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{i} }
\left[
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{u}}
\frac{\partial y_{u}}{\partial x_{s}}
\right]
\\
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{i} }
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{u}}
\;
\frac{\partial y_{u}}{\partial x_{s}}
+
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{u}}
\;
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{i} }
\frac{\partial y_{u}}{\partial x_{s}}
\\
&= 
\frac{\partial^{2} z_{t}}{\partial y_{i} y_{u}}
\;
\frac{\partial y_{u}}{\partial x_{s}}
+
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{u}}
\;
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{i} }
\frac{\partial y_{u}}{\partial x_{s}}
\\
&= 
\frac{\partial^{2} z_{t}}{\partial y_{i} y_{u}}
\;
\frac{\partial y_{u}}{\partial x_{s}}
+
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{u}}
\;
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{s} }
\frac{\partial y_{u}}{\partial y_{i} }
\\
&= 
\frac{\partial^{2} z_{t}}{\partial y_{i} y_{u}}
\;
\frac{\partial y_{u}}{\partial x_{s}}
+
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{y}}
\;
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{s} }
\delta_{i,u}
\\
&=
\frac{\partial^{2} z_{t}}{\partial y_{i} y_{u}}
\;
\frac{\partial y_{u}}{\partial x_{s}}
+
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{u}}
\;
0
\\
&=
\frac{\partial^{2} z_{t}}{\partial y_{i} y_{u}}
\;
\frac{\partial y_{u}}{\partial x_{s}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now replace this expression into the second term of the earlier equation for the Hessian of $z$ with respect to $x$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left.
H_{x} z \right\vert_{s,t,j} 
&= 
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
\,
\frac{\partial^{2} y_{i}}{\partial x_{s} x_{j}}
+
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{s}}
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
\,
\frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}
\\
&= 
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
\,
\frac{\partial^{2} y_{i}}{\partial x_{s} x_{j}}
+
\frac{\partial^{2} z_{t}}{\partial y_{i} y_{u}}
\;
\frac{\partial y_{u}}{\partial x_{s}}
\,
\frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now we can replace the partial derivative notation with the Jacobian/Hessian notation to get an expression for the Hessian of $z$ as a function of $x$ in terms of the intermediate Jacobians/Hessians:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left.
H_{x} z \right\vert_{s,t,j} 
&= 
\frac{\partial z_{t}}{\partial y_{i}}
\,
\frac{\partial^{2} y_{i}}{\partial x_{s} x_{j}}
+
\frac{\partial^{2} z_{t}}{\partial y_{i} y_{u}}
\;
\frac{\partial y_{u}}{\partial x_{s}}
\,
\frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}
\\
&= 
\left.
J_{y} z \right|_{t,i}
\,
\left.
H_{x} y \right|_{s,i,j}
+
\left.
H_{y} z \right|_{i,t,u}
\;
\left.
J_{x} y \right|_{{u,s}}
\,
\left.
J_{x} y \right|_{i,j}
\end{aligned}
$$

So for the first term:

$$
\left.
J_{y} z \right|_{t,i}
\,
\left.
H_{x} y \right|_{s,i,j}
$$
we evaluate the tensor product along the second dimension of the Jacobian of $z$ and the second dimension of the Hessian of $y$. This is because the shared index $i$ appears second for $J_{y} z$ and second for $H_{x} y$. The Numpy tensordot function accepts an argument to set which dimensions to carry out the product on.

For the second term
$$
\left.
H_{y} z \right|_{i,t,u}
\;
\left.
J_{x} y \right|_{{u,s}}
\,
\left.
J_{x} y \right|_{i,j}
$$
There are two tensor products and the shared indices indicate over which dimensions to take the products.

Comment: I've made a few changes and clarifications as the original answer had some pure LaTeX commands and some gaps in the description. Feedback welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis, in the end I performed the chain rule using indices inside loops

Comment: @whirlwind , No problem. Do you think the loop implementation you performed matches the analysis?